# Как добавить KeyListener в программу JavaFX для работы в фоновом режиме

Tags: java, javafx

Я хочу написать кликер-бота на JavaFX, мне нужно понять как сделать KeyListener, который будет принимать значения клавиш, когда программа будет работать в фоновом режиме.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Чтобы глобал хук работал в фоновом режиме нужно копать в сторону JNI